# Service / repository design in DDD

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I'm currently learning DDD, for testing purposes I'm developing a simple blog system, but I can't figure out how to correctly design my services and repositories.

I have:

- Post entity
- Post comment entity
- Post tag entity

I have a page where I would like to display all comments and tags for one specific post.

I started with the following controller action:

```
function showPost($postId) {
    try {
        $postEntity = $this->postService->find($postId);
    } catch {PostNotFoundException $e) {
        // ...
    }

    $postComments = $this->postCommentService->findAll($postEntity);
    $postTags     = $this->postTagService->findAll($postEntity);

    // return to view...  
}
```

In most of the examples available on the internet i read that it's not a good idea to work directly with entities in the controller (application layer), entites should be used only in domain services. So i tried to move them there:

```
function showPost($postId) {
    $postComments = $this->postCommentService->findAll($postId);
    $postTags     = $this->postTagService->findAll($postId);

    // return to view...  
}
```

But now i have duplicated code in my services, and I have to inject PostRepository in both services:

```
// in postCommentService
function findAll($postId) {
    try {
        $postEntity = $this->postRepository->find($postId);
    } catch (PostNotFoundException $e) {
        // ...
    }
    $postComments = $this->postCommentRepository->findAll($postEntity);
    return $postComments; // convert to DTO before return
}

// in postTagService
function findAll($postId) {
    try {
        $postEntity = $this->postRepository->find($postId);
    } catch (PostNotFoundException $e) {
        // ...
    }
    $postTags = $this->postTagRepository->findAll($postEntity);
    return $postTags; // convert to DTO before return
}
```

The third problem is that I need the postEntity (or its DTO equivalent) in my view also, so there would be another (the third) query for that in the controller.

Is there a generic solution for my problem? Query for an object (post) based on an id (postId) and its "subobjects" (comments and tags)?

Or is it okay to query for an entity in the controller and directly use it for querying the services?

Comment: You don't design repositories or services on UI use cases. How you display stuff on your page should not infuence them, or your entities. I think that reading abour CQRS could be helpful. You can use something as simple as https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/application/forum/PostQueryService.java

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dddinphp <- the participants there may be able to offer you a clearer answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a generic solution for my problem?

There's no magic.

You should probably be thinking in terms of a "view service"; something that takes a postId as an argument, and returns a DTO with what you need to build the view.

The view service in turn is going to need three methods

- postId -> post
- postId -> list(comments)
- postId -> list(tags)

The key idea is this once you have the post, the list of comments, and the list of tags, you don't actually care where they came from.  That's the point of the repository - it [hides the decision](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2979&context=compsci) about how to persist the data from the parts of the code that don't care.

```
try {
    $postEntity = $this->postRepository->find($postId);
    $postComments = $this->postCommentRepository->findAll($postId);
    $postTags = $this->postTagRepository->findAll($postId);

    return $this->createDTO($postEntity, $postComments, $postTags);
} catch (PostNotFoundException $e) {
    // ...
}
```

For use cases that are only reading from the data model, once you have the raw data that you need, you don't need to think about the repositories any longer.  It's often useful to have a clear logical separation between the code that is interacting with the repositories, and the code that is doing the work against the in memory representations of the entities.

If you wanted a more "object oriented" looking API, you could put the work of constructing the DTO into the post entity itself

```
try {
    $postEntity = $this->postRepository->find($postId);
    return $postEntity->createDTO($this->postCommentRepository, $this->postTagRepository);

} catch (PostNotFoundException $e) {
    // ...
}
```

Here, the repositories are standing in as a sort of "domain service" giving the postEntity the read capability that it needs to construct the DTO.